# tex-common error when trying to install texlive -- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, latex, texlive

I'm trying to install `texlive`.

I "purged" texlive after a "successful" installation in Ubuntu 20.04 on a new machine produced a situation where I could not compile any of the *.tex files that easily work on my other systems. So I decided to wipe that installation, and try again.

I put "purged" in quotes because, after attempting to purge `texlive` from my system (by going through the steps given in the accepted answer in [this Tex Stack Exchange post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/how-to-remove-everything-related-to-tex-live-for-fresh-install-on-ubuntu)), it appeared the process actually did not remove everything `texlive`-related as I had expected.

Nonetheless, I tried installing `texlive` again, and am now in a hopeless loop where whatever command I use -- `sudo apt-get install 'texlive-*'` or `sudo apt install texlive-full` or any of the longer, more involved ones -- I get an error that always involves `tex-common`:

```
fmtutil failed. Output has been stored in /tmp/fmtutil.L7mCqGpc Please include this file if you report a bug.

dpkg: error processing package tex-common (--configure):  installed
tex-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error
exit status 1 Errors were encountered while processing:  tex-common E:
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After each failed attempt, I go through the same steps to "purge" texlive so as to remove from my system what I hope are all vestiges of the failed attempt.

I have noticed that after going through those eight steps to remove `texlive` from my system, there are files still left over, that relate to `tex-common`. So when I try `sudo apt-get purge tex-common` and then do `locate tex-common` sixteen files/folders come up.

How can I resolve this issue so I can successfully install `texlive`?

---

N0rbert, thanks for your response. PPA... don't think I used one. Sorry, can't remember, I never had an issue with my other machines. I think I just used `sudo apt install texlive-full` or something similar. I might have installed TexWorks using the Ubuntu Software Center... wiped it using the stepwise method I mentioned above.

Output of `grep -r "^deb " /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"`:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/miktex.list:deb http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu bionic universe
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/system76-dev-ubuntu-stable-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76-dev/stable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Output of `apt-cache policy texlive-full`:

```
texlive-full:
  Installed: 2019.20200218-1
  Candidate: 2019.20200218-1
  Version table:
 *** 2019.20200218-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

---

Output of `sudo apt-get dist upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  fwupd fwupd-signed google-chrome-stable libegl-mesa0 libegl1-mesa libfwupd2 libfwupdplugin1 libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri
  libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libglx-mesa0 libmysqlclient21 libnetplan0 libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libsystemd0 libudev1
  libxatracker2 linux-firmware mesa-vulkan-drivers netplan.io python3-update-manager system76-driver system76-power systemd
  systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd udev update-manager update-manager-core
31 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 143 kB/312 MB of archives.
After this operation, 5,979 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76-dev/stable/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libegl-mesa0 amd64 21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev [143 kB]
Fetched 135 kB in 1s (240 kB/s)       
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
(Reading database ... 475587 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnss-systemd_245.4-4ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnss-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) over (245.4-4ubuntu3.11) ...
Preparing to unpack .../udev_245.4-4ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking udev (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) over (245.4-4ubuntu3.11) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libudev1_245.4-4ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libudev1:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) over (245.4-4ubuntu3.11) ...
Setting up libudev1:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) ...
(Reading database ... 475588 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../systemd-sysv_245.4-4ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd-sysv (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) over (245.4-4ubuntu3.11) ...
Preparing to unpack .../systemd-timesyncd_245.4-4ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd-timesyncd (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) over (245.4-4ubuntu3.11) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libpam-systemd_245.4-4ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpam-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) over (245.4-4ubuntu3.11) ...
Preparing to unpack .../systemd_245.4-4ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) over (245.4-4ubuntu3.11) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libsystemd0_245.4-4ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsystemd0:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) over (245.4-4ubuntu3.11) ...
Setting up libsystemd0:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) ...
(Reading database ... 475588 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libgl1-mesa-dri_21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev) over (21.2.1-2ubuntu1pop0~1631200248~20.04~4d5cd49~dev) ...
Preparing to unpack .../01-libglx-mesa0_21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglx-mesa0:amd64 (21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev) over (21.2.1-2ubuntu1pop0~1631200248~20.04~4d5cd49~dev) ...
Preparing to unpack .../02-libegl-mesa0_21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libegl-mesa0:amd64 (21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev) over (21.2.1-2ubuntu1pop0~1631200248~20.04~4d5cd49~dev) ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-libglapi-mesa_21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglapi-mesa:amd64 (21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev) over (21.2.1-2ubuntu1pop0~1631200248~20.04~4d5cd49~dev) ...
Preparing to unpack .../04-libgbm1_21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgbm1:amd64 (21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev) over (21.2.1-2ubuntu1pop0~1631200248~20.04~4d5cd49~dev) ...
Preparing to unpack .../05-google-chrome-stable_94.0.4606.71-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (94.0.4606.71-1) over (94.0.4606.54-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../06-libnetplan0_0.103-0ubuntu5~20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnetplan0:amd64 (0.103-0ubuntu5~20.04.1) over (0.102-0ubuntu1~20.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../07-netplan.io_0.103-0ubuntu5~20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking netplan.io (0.103-0ubuntu5~20.04.1) over (0.102-0ubuntu1~20.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../08-python3-update-manager_1%3a20.04.10.9_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-update-manager (1:20.04.10.9) over (1:20.04.10.7) ...
Preparing to unpack .../09-update-manager-core_1%3a20.04.10.9_all.deb ...
Unpacking update-manager-core (1:20.04.10.9) over (1:20.04.10.7) ...
Preparing to unpack .../10-update-manager_1%3a20.04.10.9_all.deb ...
Unpacking update-manager (1:20.04.10.9) over (1:20.04.10.7) ...
Preparing to unpack .../11-fwupd-signed_1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1.1~1632510283~20.04~5dec90e~dev_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fwupd-signed (1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1.1~1632510283~20.04~5dec90e~dev) over (1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1~1627329462~20.04~3e64f3f~dev) ...
Preparing to unpack .../12-libfwupd2_1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1.1~1632510283~20.04~5dec90e~dev_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfwupd2:amd64 (1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1.1~1632510283~20.04~5dec90e~dev) over (1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1~1627329462~20.04~3e64f3f~dev) ...
Preparing to unpack .../13-libfwupdplugin1_1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1.1~1632510283~20.04~5dec90e~dev_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfwupdplugin1:amd64 (1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1.1~1632510283~20.04~5dec90e~dev) over (1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1~1627329462~20.04~3e64f3f~dev) ...
Preparing to unpack .../14-fwupd_1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1.1~1632510283~20.04~5dec90e~dev_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fwupd (1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1.1~1632510283~20.04~5dec90e~dev) over (1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1~1627329462~20.04~3e64f3f~dev) ...
Preparing to unpack .../15-libegl1-mesa_21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libegl1-mesa:amd64 (21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev) over (21.2.1-2ubuntu1pop0~1631200248~20.04~4d5cd49~dev) ...
Preparing to unpack .../16-libgl1-mesa-glx_21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev) over (21.2.1-2ubuntu1pop0~1631200248~20.04~4d5cd49~dev) ...
Preparing to unpack .../17-libmysqlclient21_8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmysqlclient21:amd64 (8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) over (8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../18-libxatracker2_21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxatracker2:amd64 (21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev) over (21.2.1-2ubuntu1pop0~1631200248~20.04~4d5cd49~dev) ...
Preparing to unpack .../19-linux-firmware_1.200+system76~1632347857~20.04~9a6d09b~dev_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware (1.200+system76~1632347857~20.04~9a6d09b~dev) over (1.199+system76~1627913034~20.04~a184ea1~dev) ...
Preparing to unpack .../20-mesa-vulkan-drivers_21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev) over (21.2.1-2ubuntu1pop0~1631200248~20.04~4d5cd49~dev) ...
Preparing to unpack .../21-system76-power_1.1.18~1632516399~20.04~0bf0fc7~dev_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking system76-power (1.1.18~1632516399~20.04~0bf0fc7~dev) over (1.1.18~1632252487~20.04~4f636eb~dev) ...
Preparing to unpack .../22-system76-driver_20.04.43~1632933380~20.04~0ac2ed2~dev_all.deb ...
Unpacking system76-driver (20.04.43~1632933380~20.04~0ac2ed2~dev) over (20.04.42~1631829434~20.04~fd049c1~dev) ...
Setting up mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev) ...
Setting up libmysqlclient21:amd64 (8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) ...
Setting up libgbm1:amd64 (21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev) ...
Setting up linux-firmware (1.200+system76~1632347857~20.04~9a6d09b~dev) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-7614-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-7633-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-37-generic
Setting up libfwupd2:amd64 (1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1.1~1632510283~20.04~5dec90e~dev) ...
Setting up libnetplan0:amd64 (0.103-0ubuntu5~20.04.1) ...
Setting up libxatracker2:amd64 (21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev) ...
Setting up libegl1-mesa:amd64 (21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev) ...
Setting up tex-common (6.13) ...
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running mtxrun --generate. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... done.
Running mktexlsr /var/lib/texmf ... done.
Building format(s) --all.
    This may take some time... 
fmtutil failed. Output has been stored in
/tmp/fmtutil.VSeGny8X
Please include this file if you report a bug.

dpkg: error processing package tex-common (--configure):
 installed tex-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up udev (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up libfwupdplugin1:amd64 (1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1.1~1632510283~20.04~5dec90e~dev) ...
Setting up libglapi-mesa:amd64 (21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev) ...
Setting up python3-update-manager (1:20.04.10.9) ...
Setting up fwupd (1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1.1~1632510283~20.04~5dec90e~dev) ...
fwupd-offline-update.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
fwupd-refresh.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
Setting up google-chrome-stable (94.0.4606.71-1) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev) ...
Setting up fwupd-signed (1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1.1~1632510283~20.04~5dec90e~dev) ...
Setting up libegl-mesa0:amd64 (21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev) ...
Setting up update-manager-core (1:20.04.10.9) ...
Setting up libglx-mesa0:amd64 (21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev) ...
Setting up update-manager (1:20.04.10.9) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (21.2.1-2ubuntu2pop0~1632348269~20.04~616afda~dev) ...
Setting up systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/resolved ...
Setting up netplan.io (0.103-0ubuntu5~20.04.1) ...
Setting up systemd-timesyncd (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) ...
Setting up system76-power (1.1.18~1632516399~20.04~0bf0fc7~dev) ...
Setting up systemd-sysv (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) ...
Setting up libnss-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) ...
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-7614-generic
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up system76-driver (20.04.43~1632933380~20.04~0ac2ed2~dev) ...
INFO    product_version: 'meer6'
INFO    displayport1_force_enable_audio: Force enable audio output from DP-1 (physical HDMI 1 port.)
INFO    Skipping 'displayport1_force_enable_audio' as it was already applied
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tex-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Output of `apt-cache policy miktex`:

```
miktex:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 21.6-bionic1
  Version table:
     21.6-bionic1 500
        500 http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
     21.3-bionic1 500
        500 http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
     21.1-bionic1 500
        500 http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
     20.12-bionic1 500
        500 http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
     20.11-bionic1 500
        500 http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
     20.10-bionic1 500
        500 http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
     20.6.29-bionic1 500
        500 http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
     20.6-bionic1 500
        500 http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

Output of `sudo apt-get install tree`:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tree
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 43.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 115 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 tree amd64 1.8.0-1 [43.0 kB]
Fetched 43.0 kB in 0s (88.5 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package tree.
(Reading database ... 475613 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../tree_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tree (1.8.0-1) ...
Setting up tex-common (6.13) ...
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running mtxrun --generate. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... done.
Running mktexlsr /var/lib/texmf ... done.
Building format(s) --all.
    This may take some time... 
fmtutil failed. Output has been stored in
/tmp/fmtutil.1bdpEBPj
Please include this file if you report a bug.

dpkg: error processing package tex-common (--configure):
 installed tex-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up tree (1.8.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tex-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`
```

Output of `tree /usr/local/bin`:

```
/usr/local/bin

0 directories, 0 files
```

---

N0rbert, thanks for your fast responses. The `/tmp/fmtutil.VSeGny8X` is pretty large, over 14,000 lines. Is there a way to upload it?

Yes, running System76 meerkat hardware.

`which miktexsetup` returns nothing.

Output of `dpkg -l`:

Apologies, but how do I upload the file that contains the output? It's another biggie

Comment: Do you use any PPA to get texlive installed on your system? Please share full error output. Also show output of `grep -r "^deb " /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"` and `apt-cache policy texlive-full` .

Comment: N0rbert, thanks for your response. PPA... don't think I used one. Sorry, can't remember, I never had an issue with my other machines. I think I just used `sudo apt install texlive-full` or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** Do not use/mix MikTex with deb-packaged TeXLive. Do not use/mix binary TeXLive with deb-packaged TeXLive. Use only deb-packaged TeXLive instead to prevent problems.

**Details**. The system has active MikTex repository. To prevent possible conflicts with TexLive disable it using commands below:

```
miktexsetup cleanup
sudo miktexsetup --shared=yes cleanup

sudo apt autoremove --purge miktex
sudo rm -v /etc/apt/sources.list.d/miktex.list
sudo rm -v /etc/fonts/conf.d/09-miktex.conf
sudo apt-get update
```

and then use only TexLive.

During chat session we discovered that system had local installation of Texlive. We did this by using the following steps:

1. remove all TeX related packages with

   ```
   sudo apt autopurge $(dpkg -l | grep "TeX" | grep ^ii | awk '{print $2}')
   ```

   And what is interesting - removal process has several lines like `dpkg: warning: while removing texlive-latex-extra, directory '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stex/statements' not empty so not removed`. So we classified them and removed by commands like:

   ```
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/fonts/truetype/artemisia
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/fonts/truetype/baskerville
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/fonts/truetype/bodoni-classic
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/fonts/truetype/didot
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/fonts/truetype/didot-classic
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/fonts/truetype/gazis
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/fonts/truetype/gentium
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/fonts/truetype/neohellenic
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/fonts/truetype/olga
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/fonts/truetype/porson
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/fonts/truetype/solomos
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/fonts/truetype/theokritos
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/fonts/type1/texlive-fonts-recommended
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/achemso
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/acro
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/animate
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cdpbundl
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/circuitikz
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/dtk
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/endfloat
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/exsheets
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/invoice
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/isodoc
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3experimental/l3str
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lettre
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makedtx
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minitoc
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nomencl
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfx
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pkgloader
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stex/cmath
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stex/dcm
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stex/hwexam
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stex/metakeys
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stex/mikoslides
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stex/modules
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stex/omdoc
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stex/omtext
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stex/presentation
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stex/problem
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stex/sproof
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stex/sref
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stex/statements
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stex/workaddress
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sttools
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xdoc
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm
   sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm-math
   ```
2. then we tried to find the *texlive*-related files and folders which does not came from deb-packages by using command below

   ```
   sudo find /bin /etc /lib /lib64 /opt /sbin /srv /usr /var -iname "*texlive*" -exec dpkg -S {} \; > /dev/null
   ```

   and it shown the following

   > ```
   > dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/share/texlive
   > ```

   and this folder has *98 directories, 482 files* according to `tree /usr/share/texlive`.

   So we removed this folder as simple as `sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/texlive` and then proceed.
3. Install all needed stuff as usual

   ```
   sudo apt-get install texlive-base
   sudo apt-get install tex-common
   sudo apt-get install texlive-full
   ```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately that failed too, with the same tex-common related error. The command `miktexsetup cleanup` said it couldn't find miktexsetup. Why did you ask about System76 hardware? I originally wondered if that might have something to do with it, since I've never encountered anything similar on my other machines

Comment: Sometimes system76 PPA creates issues. Do you really run on [meer6](https://tech-docs.system76.com/models/meer6/README.html) product? What do you have in `/tmp/fmtutil.VSeGny8X` and `/tmp/fmtutil.1bdpEBPj` files? Please upload full output of `dpkg -l` to pastebin and share a link.

Comment: how can I share the output of `dpkg -l`? how do I upload the file that contains the output?

Comment: Please answer the question about System76 hardware. If you are not using it, then we can remove the PPA without any further issues. You run `dpkg -l > ~/somefile` and then upload contents of `~/somefile` to pastebin. Also upload both `/tmp/fmtutil.VSeGny8X` and `/tmp/fmtutil.1bdpEBPj` .

Comment: yes, all this is happening on a System76 meerkat

Comment: sorry, I don't know what you mean by "upload contents of ~/somefile to pastebin." I can't figure out how to upload and paste a link. Obviously it doesn't mean paste contents, because the contents exceed the character limit

Comment: Visit https://pastebin.com/ and paste file contents there.

Comment: ah, okay done. contents of `dpkg -l` https://pastebin.com/V5BTVEU8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130189/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-prokaryote).